# WPF - Using DynamicResource into a loose XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, resources

I'm doing a plug-in for an external app, and i need to put a loose xaml which contains my values.

I did it successfully using a path like "pack://siteoforigin,,,/Strings.xaml".

But I can't succeed by putting it into a parent folder (except using absolute paths).

I mean, I have something like this :

```
/ProjectRoot
    /Bin
         main.exe
         plugin.dll
    /Conf
         strings.xaml
```

The app is started from the Conf folder, and call the main.exe from here like this :

```
 ..\Bin\main.exe
```

How can I refer to my xaml ?

Of course a path like " pack://siteoforigin,,,/../Conf/strings.xaml " isn't working.

There is other way than putting it into the same (or subfolder) as my dll ?

Can I use an environmnent variable which can give me the starting path ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, i just add to remove the reference to the dictionnary ressource. The wpf core found automatically the file and manage it....

So i just remove the "include".